# Max /28 subnets in a 10.0.0.0/16 VPC

Tags: amazon-vpc

AWS documentation states I can have 200 subnets per VPC without requesting additional capacity. I'm looking to create /28 CIDR subnets that can each provide 16 (or 11 usable) ip addresses and I want to create the maximum number of subnets in the VPC. What CIDR should I assign to the VPC itself? (maybe 10.0.0.0/16?) And what are some example CIDRs to define the subnets?

Comment: Side-question: Can you elaborate on *why* you wish to create 200 subnets? If you are wishing to isolate resources, Security Groups might be a better option.

Comment: You really do need a compelling reason to want to do this, becuase it's definitely a departure from standard practice.  Many resources, such as Lambda functions and Application Load Balancers, will not be able to scale properly on such small subnets, and the network is software-defined, meaning that being on the same subnet or a different subnet results in no performance difference... and concepts like multicast, broadcast, and collision domains are all meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `/20` network, which would give 4096 addresses.

That would give 256 subnets * 16 addresses (`/28`) = 4096

But, feel free to use something larger.

You might want to automate the creation of that many subnets.

See: [CIDR, Subnet Masks, and Usable IP Addresses Quick Reference Guide (Cheat Sheet)](http://droptips.com/cidr-subnet-masks-and-usable-ip-addresses-quick-reference-guide-cheat-sheet)

Comment: That looks promising! I think this page shows the breakdown of subnets? http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=10.0.0.0&mask1=20&mask2=255.255.255.240